# Sequelizejs, how sort field values when creating an index

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have some 'invite' model:

```
'use strict';

export default function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('Invite', {
      userFromId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        modal: 'User',
        key: '_id',
        onDelete: 'cascade'
      },
      userToId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        modal: 'User',
        key: '_id',
        onDelete: 'cascade'
      },
      accept1: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
      },
      accept2: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false
      }

    },{
      indexes: [
        {
          name:'id',
          unique: true,
          fields: ['userFromId','userToId'],
        }]
    }
  );
}
```

I need that when i  to create a new 'Invite', a combination of 'userFromId' and 'userToId' created one index regardless of who gets invited. For example invite `{userFromId:1,userToId:2}` and `{userFromId:2,userToId:1}` must have the same index.

I use sequelize: 3.29.0 and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using a database index because `[1, 2] != [2, 1]`. If you want to enforce this type of uniqueness one option is to create a new field with a unique index and set it's value to be `lower + : + higher` so that in the example above you always end up with `1:2`.

```js
// Create a field called 'uniqueKey' set to the sorted IDs
export default function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define('Invite', {
      // ... other fields
      uniqueKey: {
        type: DataTypes.String,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: function() {
           // create an array of the IDs, sort, then join with :
           return [
               this.getDataValue('userFromId'),
               this.getDataValue('userToId'),
           ].sort().join(':');
        },
      },
      // ... other fields
    },{
      indexes: [
        {
          name:'uniqueKey',
          unique: true,
          fields: ['uniqueKey'],
        }]
    }
  );
}
```

You can see how the `defualtValue` is calculated here, the key/result is the same regardless of the order of IDs:

```
[1,2].sort().join(':');
"1:2"
[2,1].sort().join(':');
"1:2"
```